# ServiceStack DateTime Local not UTC

Tags: datetime, servicestack

I am having a problem with the Servicestack I am getting a datetime from an external system and if I am using the DateTimeOffset I can se that the time is 
15:00:00 +0200 I know that this is utc time stamp but Servicestack set is as local time this results in the time moving the wrong way.

I have read that you can tell the servicestack to allways use UTC but I cant find any where how to set it up and I don't know it this will help me.

from 
Kenneth Foli Jørgensen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell [ServiceStack.Text's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) JSON/JSV/CSV text serializers to use UTC with:

```
JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;
```

Comment: the problem is how do i use this 
JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;


where am i impleminding JsConfig

Comment: Just refer to it fully qualified: ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig
I set it in my AppHost configure() method